What are the differences (if any) between "task notifications" and "calendar notifications"?
It is possible to customize the notification sounds for Google calendar for Android cellphones. For example, a task-notification can sound like a windchime playing and and a calendar notification can could sound like a car horn.
Are task notifications a subset of of calendar notifications?
Are task notifications mutually exclusive from calendar notifications?
Suppose that there is a Google Calendar event at 1:00PM on Monday.
Will the event notification play the task sound or will the event notification play the calendar notification sound?

Task notifications are mutually exclusive from calendar notifications.
Calendar event notification will play the calendar notification sound, while task (previously reminder) notification will play task notification sound.
